# Geo Mashup Maps show only specified categories

Tags: google-maps, geo-data

I'm using the Geo Mashup plugin to display maps on my site. I've changed a pages template, so it now only lists pages from certain categories instead of listing them all, which has now effected my global map to only show maps from the first categories I specify should be listed.

I'm using: `<?php echo GeoMashup::map(); ?>` to show the map. Is there a way to give the map a list of categories it should be displaying? I can't find anything to suggest how you would do this.

Comment: Nm, figured it out: <?php echo GeoMashup::map( 'map_content=global&map_cat=1,2,3,4,5' . $cat->term_id ); ?>

Comment: Please add this as answer. Btw: You can add code formatting to comments too.

Answer (score 2):

Nm, figured it out:

```
<?php echo GeoMashup::map( 'map_content=global&map_cat=1,2,3,4,5' . $cat->term_id ); ?>
```